# Permission denied when chmoding

Tags: windows, bash, permissions, adobe, chmod

I want to remove an Adobe folder with empty subfolders. I am using Git Bash on Windows 8 to `chmod -R 777 Adobe/` but I am getting this error: `changing permissions of 'insert_directory_here': Permission denied`. Does anyone know what I can possibly do to delete this empty folders/subfolders? Thank you.

Comment: Windows doesn't file have permissions like unix. I doubt that that would work.

Comment: I see. So how would I go about deleting that directory?